# react server does not start due to proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I created a react app using create-react-app and have a proxy inside it which sends a request to my backend server in localhost:5000. the react app is running on localhost:3000 and I am using concurrently to run both the servers simultaneously. The problem is since I added a setupPorxy file in my react app it just doesn't work. the server never starts and if I delete setupProxy, the server starts normally but then the proxy does not work anymore and I want to make use of proxy because I am using cookies and I want to avoid cors errors.

Package.json file for my backend server. you can see how concurrently is setup.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.1.1",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "mongodb": "^5.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "passport": "^0.5.3",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

setupProxy.js

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
    export default function (app) {
        app.use(
            '/auth/google',
            createProxyMiddleware({
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true,
            })
        );
    };
```

Either one the above files has a bug because other files do not have any connection with the proxy.

expected behaviour:

1. the react app should load like normally.
2. the proxy should work normally and the user should be redirected to the OAuth flow meaning to google.